# Accessing full layer name raster stack R

Tags: r, raster, names

I have a raster stack for climate data where each layer represents a measure of daily precipitation. The names of each layer are long and include the month, year, and day each layer represents.

```
prcpSmall
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 790, 812, 641480, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : 1590250, 2402250, 149500, 939500  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names       : FIA_DAYME//03.2015.10, FIA_DAYME//03.2015.11, FIA_DAYME//03.2015.12, FIA_DAYME//03.2015.13, FIA_DAYME//03.2015.14, FIA_DAYME//03.2015.15
```

For example, data in the first layer were collected on March 10th, 2015. But, when I use the `names()` the time stamp is gone.

```
names(prcpSmall)
[1] "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.10" "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.11"
[3] "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.12" "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.13"
[5] "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.14" "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.15"
```

The complete dataset include over 4000 layers.  Is there a way I access the full layer name with the time stamp information for each layer?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please post you sample data via `dput(prcpSmall)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only show a few days for one month, but from the example you provide, it would seem that you can do:

```
# n <- names(prcpSmall)
n <- c("FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.10", "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.11", "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.12", "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.13", "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.14", "FIA_DAYMET_prcp_2003.2015.15")

d <- gsub("FIA_DAYMET_prcp_20", "", n)

as.Date(d, "%m.%Y.%d")
# [1] "2015-03-10" "2015-03-11" "2015-03-12" "2015-03-13" "2015-03-14" "2015-03-15"
```

Comment: This code worked great.  Thanks for sharing the gsub function, I hadn't seen it before.